# kineticjs exception on stage.destroyChildren

Tags: kineticjs

When I am cleaning up my stage I call

```
stage.destroyChildren();
```

When I have done this in the past it works fine.
for a new project I am calling it and I get the following exception:

> 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'f.getCanvas')

f is not one of my variables.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is that the cleanup might be being called when an object is being dragged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by putting it in a setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){function_that_calls_destroyChildren();},50);
```

this solves my problem. I think it does have to do with a race condition with the drag.